# Plotting with ColorFunction -> GrayLevel - no black

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, import, color

This is probably a fairly trivial question, yet I have been unable to find an answer - help would be much appreciated! :)

I am trying to plot a 28 x 28 matrix (tabulated data given [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PP2t8tp6)), containing continuous pixels values on the interval [0;1]. I am using MatrixPlot and ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, so that 0 comes out as black and 1 as white, and all values inbetween will cover the gray spectrum. MatrixPlot produces a lovely 28 x 28 matrix plot - however, for some reason it uses a medium gray for 0, and scales the remaining values accordingly on the gray spectrum, with 1 still being white.

This is the code used:

```
input1 = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PP2t8tp6"];
MatrixPlot[input1, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Mesh -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/1, ImageSize -> 300]
```

The resulting image:

[image]

Adding a file extension (.dat, .csv, .txt) and adding separators made no difference - I also tried forcing the color spectrum with ColorRule, but no luck.

Comment: I have nowhere to upload the file for linking - but the data is of the form described above, outputted from my program with simple spaces "   " as separators and '\n' as newline. :)

Comment: Please prodive your inputfile, it will be easier for everyone. You can paste it in your question or on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/). The simplest way is to copy/paste `input1` on pastebin.

Comment: Seems a little space consuming - but I've added it to the post. :)

Comment: Try `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

Comment: Spot on, that worked - thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to prevent scaling of the data with the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`

```
data = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PP2t8tp6"];
MatrixPlot[data, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]